# Silverlight 4 Bind selected items' (more than one) properties to a textbox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, multiple-instances

I have an editor where the user selects a photo from a listbox in SL4, and edits the values like title, description, tags in a panel next to the list. The textboxes have `Binding` is XAML to the listbox's `SelectedItem`'s appropriate properties, and it works nice. However, I want to be able to select multiple photos at the same time, and say, set tags of each. I don't know the exact name of the problem but I tried to explain, it is a very basic functionally in any software, select multiple items and edit a property, and it will be edited for all of them. If the properties are different, the textbox would display `(multiple values)` and if I don't touch the field, nothing happens to those fields. Is this possible in XAML? I'm pretty sure up until SL version 4 is released, Microsoft guys would have thought a clever solution to this multiple-selection problem. If yes, how (please, XAML and Binding based declarative as possible or everything easily gets messed up). If there is no starightforward way, what is the cleanest/best practice of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListBox.SelectedItems` to enumerate and change the property of each item in the selected list. The `ListBox` should have `SelectionMode as Multiple`.

Its not a proper way to bind multiple items properties to a textbox, as we don't know what to show when these items have different values, & its better to have ListBox, and all its properties binding to a collection and its properties

Comment: Ok, how do I do it then? My current code has an `ImageOption` control, with the appropriate bindings inside. It has a `Photo` property which takes my custom class `PhotoSummary` and binds the interior elements to its properties. I've got `<my:ImageOption Photo="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPhotos, Path=SelectedItem}"  />` where `CurrentPhotos` is my `ListBox`. This works pretty nice with a single selection of photo from the list, how will I implement your solution. (code example please)

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu: you can create an `instance` of `PhotoSummary` `PS` and bind the `Photo` to that `PS` & `OnSelectionChanged` of `ListBox` you can update `PS`. Have a `PropertyChanged` event on `PS` and when the property you want is changed, then you update property of all items in `CurrentPhotos.SelectedItems`. You can think on these lines in your case

Comment: well, if there is no built-in simpler mechanism, i think i'll be going with that.